# Angular UI: How to trigger typeahead even if a value is selected?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Since 1.0.0 of Angular UI Bootstrap `typeahead-min-length=0` was introduced. With this typehead can be triggered when the input is focused. However, if a typeahead value is selected, typeahed is no longer triggered on focus.

So, how to show typeahead even if ngModel is bound to a value?

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/FP8frHEfwm4vAq9gc2W0?p=preview) example

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is beyond the scope of the normal use case of what we believe to be the proper use of a typeahead widget.  Once a value is selected, it's selected.  If you want to change it via the typeahead dropdown, you need to clear out all or a portion of the selected value to see it.

If you simply MUST have this feature, you might take a look at the angular-ui/ui-select widget which provides the functionality you seek.

You might also consider playing with the `is-open` property of the typeahead directive to see whether or not you can control it's opened state.